# How to use the horizontal scrollbar while keeping the UniformToFill property of the ViewBox inside the ScrollViewer?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ViewBox containing a few stackpanels which I want to stretch when I resize my window. I was able to get this behavior using the property `Stretch="UniformToFill"` 
However resizing causes some items to get outside the window, I have thus implemented a ScrollViewer to solve this.
The vertical scrollbar works fine, but once I enable the horizontal scrollbar, the viewbox stops stretching the way I want. 
I have researched and tried to solve this, 2 solutions came up, none of which worked:

Solution in xaml:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >

    <Viewbox x:Name="MainViewBox" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}}, Path=ActualWidth}" >

...
    </Viewbox>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This solution shows the horizontal bar while keeping the stretching property, but the scrollbar does not change size while I resize, which makes it useless.

Solution using code in C# (after defining a scrollbar in the xaml code):

```
bool need_scrollbarH = false;

    private void ScrollViewer_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((ScrollViewer)sender).ActualWidth < MainViewBox.ActualWidth)
            need_scrollbarH = true;  
    }

private void hScrollBar_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
if (need_scrollbarH)
    {
        this.Left = (hScrollBar.Value - hScrollBar.Minimum) / (hScrollBar.Maximum - hScrollBar.Minimum) * (this.Width);

        }
    }
```

I have tried to shift the content of the window using this code, but it only shifted the entire window's position...

I have run out of solutions, hope someone could give me some insight into this.

I can't share the entire code or the design, this is however the document outline:
[Document Outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw0jJ.jpg)
And the general design:
[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNfdZ.png)

Comment: Can you add some screenshots of the application's layout to better explain the problem you are dealing with?  The XAML for the content you are trying to scale would also be helpful.  I have a feeling this might be more easily solved with a different layout container.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I can't share the entire code since it's too long  (I'm only trying to fix some stuff with the layout not working from the start). I just edited and added the document outline and the general design of the application

Comment: Do you actually want the content to *scale* rather than *resize*?  Based on your screenshot, I'd expect you want it to resize.  From your layout, a 2 column, 2 row `Grid`, without the Viewboxes,  would seem to be a better layout choice to me.